# How to check an iCloud id existence programmatically using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, icloud

I want to make an API where I can check any iCloud id existence. For achieving this I twist iCloud native password recovery API.

https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid From this page you can recover iCloud password. If you enter an Apple id that doesn't exist then the page will throw an error otherwise it will send you the next step.

I use this API in my nodejs app to check iCloud id existence and it works fine as expected at my local server in development mode. The problem is when I deploy the app in production mode it throws (Request failed with status code 502) error

Here is the code which I wrote for check iCloud id

```
const axios = require("axios");

exports.verifyICloudId = async (req, res) => {
  const { appleId } = req.params;

  const { data } = await axios.post(
    "https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid",
    {
      id: appleId
    }
  );

  if (data.name === appleId)
    return res.json({
      isExist: false,
      message: `${appleId} doesn't exist on iCloud`
    });

  return res.json({ isExist: true, message: `${appleId} exist on iCloud` });
};
```

**Is there any way to run this code perfectly in the production(Currently I'm using Heroku)?**

Or

**Is there any alternative way to check iCloud id existence?**

Comment: What line is erroring in your code? Also, are you defining the node and npm versions in your package.json file? If not Heroku will build your app with the stack default and buildtime.

Comment: @travega I've defined node version  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.0"
  }

It works perfectly in my local machine but it throws 502 bad requests in Heroku